# How to use stream cipher to encrypt TCP data?

Tags: networking, encryption, cryptography, stream-cipher

i try to use chacha20 encryption in my network software but i encounter a problem

if i encrypt 4 bytes data: `0x01 0x02 0x03 0x04` on server

and get the ciphertext: `0xd2 0xd3 0xc4 0xd5`, then send it to client

the client may receive <= 4bytes at a time

provided that client only recv `0xd2 0xd3` at first ,

it can decrypt data properly and get plaintext `0x01 0x02`

but when client recv the last 2 bytes `0xc4 0xd5`

it seems that the data can't be decrypt using the same nonce and key

so is there a way to solve the problem

adding length data as prefix before sending is a solution,but it's weird because i am using stream cipher.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of restarting the ChaCha20 cipher instance (or, more generically, *context*) you should keep it alive.

Most cryptographic API's will allow you to perform piecemeal encryption / decryption. That usually means calling an `update` method for the first part and second part, generally followed by a `final` method when the end of the plaintext / ciphertext is detected. Depending on the API you should expect output for each of these methods.

Only if your API doesn't allow you to handle the stream correctly then you should aggregate the ciphertext and perform the decryption on the full ciphertext.

Answer (score 1):

ChaCha20 generates a stream, using the key and the nonce. Let `(S0, S1, S2, S3)` the first bytes of the stream, and `(M0, M1, M2, M3)` the first 4 bytes of your message.

The ciphertext will be computed as `(M0⊕S0, M1⊕S1, M2⊕S2, M3⊕S3)`. This is if you have `M0...M3` readily available.

If you encrypt `(M0, M1)` then `(M2, M3)` using the same key and nonce, you will end up with `(M0⊕S0, M1⊕S1)` and `(M2⊕S0, M3⊕S1)`. Which cannot be decrypted using `(C0⊕S0, C1⊕S1, C2⊕S2, C3⊕S3)`.

Even worse, since `S0` and `S1` have been reused with different messages, an attacker can recover them knowing any message.

The easiest thing to do in order to avoid this is to buffer the data until you reach the block size, and then encrypt the whole block, instead of trying to encrypt partial blocks.

Comment: Also note that prefixing messages with the length is almost always necessary when using TCP, as you can hardly predict how many packets the message will be sent as,

Comment: You're not reading the question correctly, the issue is at decryption, not encryption.

Comment: Unless an unusual mode was chosen for "chacha20 encryption", encryption and decryption are the same operation. Maybe I didn't understand the question correctly. I read it as "why `Dk,n(m0||m1) != Dk,n(m0)||Dk,n(m1)`?

Comment: Yes, that's how I read it as well. But according to the question c0 | c1 = Ek,n(m0 | m1) was computed. Then it was decrypted using Dk,n(c0) | Dk,n(c1) which is obviously incorrect. So the ciphertext was split, not the plaintext (message).